# Matrix equation and Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

I have a matrix equation involving square real matrices of the form:
$$X(X^{T} \odot A) + (X \odot A)X^{T} = B$$
where $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product. How can I determine a solution for X?

Any suggestions or references will be appreciated.